# TypeError: func() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I'm new to python but I know that self is automatically passed.I'm unable to understand why am I getting this error and I get the same error with getGraph function as well 2 required 1 given.
What is going wrong here?

CreateDoc is in CeleryTasks.py and insert_manager in MongoTriggers.py

```
    @app.task
    def createDoc(self):
        print ("CeleryTasks:CreateDoc")
        if 'refs' not in self.data:
            return

        print(self.data['refs'])

        for id in self.data['refs']:
            doc = self.db[self.collName].find_one({'_id': id})
            if doc is None:
                insertedID = self.db[self.collName].insert_one({
                    "_id": id
                })

                print (insertedID)

    #Trigger on Mongo Operations
    def insert_manager(op_document):
        print("Data Inserted")
        # pprint.pprint (op_document)
        data = op_document['o']
        ns = op_document['ns'].split('.')
        # pprint.pprint (data)
        docID = op_document['o']['_id']
        tasks = CeleryTasks(port, docID, dbName, collectionName, data)
        tasks.createDoc()
        tasks.getGraph.delay(docID)
```

Comment: Hi, which line cause this error?

Comment: tasks.createDoc.delay()
its equivalent to tasks.createDoc() this also gives the error.

Comment: You need to provide how long time to delay example `tasks.createDoc.delay()` will delay 6 secs

Comment: its not that. I already told if its equivalent to tasks.createDoc(). no need for dealy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is always passed when it's method of class.

Celery tasks are independent functions. You can add them `self` arguments by adding `bind=True` via the `app` decorator but it is used for a different purpose: [bounded tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks)

Comment: yes! it worked. Basically, I could've done without passing self and pass other parameters required for the function. But then, if I pass self and make the Celery Task a Bound Task. It gives me an error inside the function when i use self. 
Do you know why this happens? e.g.

`@app.task(bind=True)
    def createDoc(self, db, collName, data):
        db = self.db
`
it gives error **AttributeError: 'createDoc' object has no attribute 'db'**

Comment: I already did upvote it. But it says my reputation is below 15 so they won't show it. Anyways thanks.

Comment: `def __init__(self, port, docID, dbName, collName, data):
        self.port = port
        self.docID = docID
        self.dbName = dbName
        self.collName = collName
        self.data = data
        self.client = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=port, username='admin', password='password')
        self.db = self.client[dbName]`

**init func**